# My bot doesn't give role, but it doesn't send error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

(Sorry for my english)My bot must give role by reaction on emoji, but it doesn't do it. But it doesn't send error-message. Please help.
My code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".",intents = discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print(discord.__version__)
  
  Channel = client.get_channel(815949348948934716)
  Text= "Выбери свою роль"
  Moji = await Channel.send(Text)
  await Moji.add_reaction('')
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
  
  Channel = client.get_channel(815949348948934716)
  if reaction.message.channel.id != Channel:
    return
  if reaction.emoji == "":
    
    Role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="PUBG")
    await user.add_roles(Role)
    
client.run("My token")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use an event called `on_raw_reaction_add`. You might want to read the [Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_raw_reaction#discord.on_raw_reaction_add).

**Now to the further procedure:**

1. Define the event:

```py
    @client.event
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload): # We use payload
```

2. Define the role(s):

```py
guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id) # Define the guild
member = get(guild.members, id=payload.user_id) # Get the member from the guild
# channel and message IDs should be integer:
if payload.channel_id == Channel_ID and payload.message_id == Message_ID: # Inser your ID's
    if str(payload.emoji) == "YourEmoji":
        role = get(payload.member.guild.roles, name='RoleName') # ID also possible.
```

3. Add the role:

```py
if role is not None:
    await payload.member.add_roles(role)
```

So your entire code would be:

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
    guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
    member = get(guild.members, id=payload.user_id)
    if payload.channel_id == Channel_ID and payload.message_id == Message_ID:
        if str(payload.emoji) == "YourEmoji":
            role = get(payload.member.guild.roles, name='RoleName') # Or id='RoleID'
        else:
            role = get(guild.roles, name=payload.emoji)
        if role is not None:
            await payload.member.add_roles(role) # Add the role
```

To add more roles just use `elif` statements.

***What are we doing?***

- Send a message into the defined channel `(Channel_ID)`
- Add a role when someone reacts with the defined emoji to the message

Comment: I tried to fix my bot with your code, but it send error [line 28, in on_raw_reaction_add
    if role is not None:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'role' referenced before assignment

Comment: Yes, I have . But my user doesn't has role, when he react

Comment: @HackJonny I edited my answer with an `else` statement. The full code works fine for me, make sure nobody has the role when reacting.

Comment: Thanks!!! I have already fixed my code. You are the best!!! Thanks!!!